# Prove that none of the integers $11,111,1111,...$ are squares of an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, repunit-numbers

Please check my proof. Thank you!

Proof: $11,111,1111,...$ can all be written as follows
$\underbrace{111...}_{\text{k times}}=1+10(\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}10^n)$

Let us assume $1+10(\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}10^n)=s^2$ where $s\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Then this means $s^2|1$ and $s^2|10$. The only possible $s^2$ is then $1$.

It is obvious that $1$ does not work. So this means there is no $s$ such that  $1+10(\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}10^n)=s^2$. So we conclude that none of $11,111,1111,...$ are squares of an integer.

Edit: Once again... this proof is wrong. Please look at the answers below.

Correct Attempt:
I shall try induction.
We see that $11\cong3(\text{mod 4})$ .
Now assume that $\underbrace{111...}_{\text{k times}}\cong3(\text{mod 4})$

Then for $\underbrace{111...}_{\text{k+1 times}}$ we see that the last dividend in the long division is $31$. So the largest possible last digit is $7$ and $7\times4=28$ and $31-28=3$. The remainder is therefore $3$. And so, $\underbrace{111...}_{\text{k+1 times}}\cong3(\text{mod 4})$.
However, we know that square numbers(mentioned to me by https://math.stackexchange.com/users/279515/brahadeesh ) are either $0$ or $1$ in $\text{mod 4}$. So we conclude that all of them cannot be perfect squares.

Comment: What do you mean in the sentence: "$s^2|1$ and $s^2|10$. The only possible $s^2$ is then $1$"?

Comment: It's not true that, if $c \mid a + b$ then $c \mid a$ and $c \mid b$. For example, take $a = b = 1$ and $c = 2$.

Comment: $s^2$ divides 1 and $s^2$ divides 10.

Comment: How about $10^2$? $10^2$ divides $1$ and $10^2$ divides $10$.

Comment: $10^2$ doesn't divide $1$ and $10$

Comment: The update looks kind of alright. Note that the method of induction is not really necessary here - specifically, how did you find out that "the last dividend in the long division is $31$" when considering the number with $k+1$ ones? You did not need to use the induction hypothesis anywhere to conclude that, I'm sure. So, you will have directly shown that all these numbers are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ when you complete the justification that the remainder is $31$.

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298234/prove-that-none-of-11-111-1111-dots-is-the-perfect-square-of-an-intege/2614658#2614658)

Comment: I did use the induction hypothesis for 111... k times having a remainder of 3. So the last dividend of 111... k+1 times is 31.

Comment: But yea, I think it's quite obvious that the last dividend is always 31 after 11. So induction is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, I see! Right, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Let us assume $1+10(\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}10^n)=s^2$ where $s\in\Bbb{Z}$.
>
> Then this means $s^2|1$ and $s^2|10$.

I don't follow this implication, how do you argue that $s^2 \mid 1$ and $s^2 \mid 10$? Indeed, as [@user804886](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/804886/user804886) notes in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743458/prove-that-none-of-the-integers-11-111-1111-are-squares-of-an-integer/3743465#comment7697890_3743458) under your question, $c \mid a + b$ does **not** imply that $c \mid a$ and $c \mid b$.

---

One way to prove this is to note (exercise!) that a square is always congruent to either $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. But the numbers in your sequence are all congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, so none of them can be a square.