# Prove that $11,111,111.....$ is not a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, solution-verification, repunit-numbers

I know there are many other same related questions, but as my profile says I don't have a mentor, I just wanted you guys to check my solution.

First I noticed that,
$11$ = $10 + 1$,

$111$ = $10^2+10+1$,

Similarly, $\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{n\,\text{times}}$ = $10^{n-1}+10^{n-2}+...+10+1$,

which  can easily be evaluated as it is a finite geometric series.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i=\frac{10^n-1}{9}$$ for $n \ge
2$.

After this, I checked perfect square modulo $4$,

Let $j$ be any integer, then if $j$ is even, then $j=2k \Rightarrow j^2 = 4k^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$

and if $j$ is odd then, $j = 2k+1 \Rightarrow j^2 = 4k^2+4k+1 \equiv 1 (\mod4)$

Then, Since $\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{n\,\text{times}} = \frac{10^n-1}{9} \Rightarrow (9) (\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{n\,\text{times}}) = {10^n-1}$ $\equiv$ $2^n-1$ $(\mod 4)$

$\Rightarrow (\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{n\,\text{times}}) \equiv 2^n-1 \mod 4$

Since for $n \ge 2, 2^n$ is always a multiple of $4$. Hence,

$\Rightarrow (\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{n\,\text{times}}) \equiv -1 \mod 4$

$\Rightarrow (\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{n\,\text{times}}) \equiv 3\mod 4$

But a perfect square leaves remainder $0$ if it is even and $1$ if it is odd. So, clearly for

$n \ge 2,$  $(\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{n\,\text{times}})$ is not a perfect square.

I know there are other questions related to this but I just wanted to verify if my solution was correct. Thank you and suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems well to me :)

Comment: Since you started with $n\geq 2$, the proof looks good.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review!

Comment: Instead of the finite geometric series you could use that $111\ldots111 = 111\ldots1  \cdot 100 + 11$ for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743458/prove-that-none-of-the-integers-11-111-1111-are-squares-of-an-integer)

Comment: All you need to check the the number ends with $11$ which $3\bmod(4)$ so they cannot be perfect square number.

Comment: Others have commented on shorter ways through - when you have solved a problem like this it is always worth reviewing which of the steps was necessary and whether there might be a shorter way through using the key insights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that none of $\{11, 111, 1111,\dots \}$ is the perfect square of an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298234/prove-that-none-of-11-111-1111-dots-is-the-perfect-square-of-an-intege)

Answer (score -4):

base 3:  102 * 102 = 11111
base 7:   26 *  26 = 1111

These disprove the assertion.

In decimal, any number 11 modulo 100 is 3 mod 4, and is thus not square.